# Roblox Macbook Script Editor (Applescript) Text to Write but with Numbers

Tags: applescript, roblox

So I've been using applescript to script music for Roblox Piano, but I've noticed that it doesn't repeat numbers. Is there a way to include numbers? Although I swear the "characters" includes numbers.

```
set texttowrite to ""
tell application "Roblox" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with i from 1 to count characters of texttowrite
        keystroke (character i of texttowrite)
        delay 0.0315
    end repeat
end tell
```

I've test it in chat and it will type them in a chat box. But it just won't play them on the keyboard strangely. Could this be a roblox issue?

Comment: You're going to have to provide us with information about Roblox Piano.  I'd be surprised if there are (m)any people who know much about this _and_ know AppleScript.  I had a look online to try and get some insight about what the nature of this application is, and I've still got no idea.  But it doesn't appear to involve a  "physical" keyboard in either a software or hardware sense, but rather a bitmap rendering of one inside a gaming world.  Am I interpreting what I saw correctly ?

Comment: **PS.** In this instance, initiate your repeat loop as `repeat with c in texttowrite`.  Then call **`keystroke c`** in place of the current command call.  This will allow it to cope with both a unary string value as well as a list of characters and numerical values (in case that was somehow an issue).  It's also much more efficient.

Comment: @CJK I will start using keystroke c instead, then. Also, yes, it is a virtual piano. I am using Applescript to auto-track piano keys in the form of qwerty. I wish I knew how to provide the coding for a virtual piano, but I am not the creator, so I'm not sure how it's coded.

Comment: The code isn't necessary at this stage. If you can describe the nature of the application, it will help give us an idea what sort of interaction _would_ be appropriate and/or achievable. Applications on macOS are usually one of four types: ⓵ a native macOS GUI app built with physical UI elements belonging to the OS; ⓶ a web app, that you use in-browser; ⓷ a GUI app that blends macOS nativity (at the very least, a window frame) whilst rendering content that could include web content; **or** ⓸ a fully customised GUI made of physical elements, none (or few) of which belong to the OS.

Comment: If it's likely to be ⓵ or ⓶, then that's more encouraging than if it's likely to be ⓷ or (hopefully not) ⓸.  Perhaps if you can provide a screenshot of the application (including the window containing it showing both the keyboard and chat), this would be easier and most descriptive.  You may not be able to upload a picture as you're new, but you can provide a link to one if you upload it to imgur, or similar.